# Virgin Australia and Swiss Airlines frequent flyer points

Tags: loyalty-programs, virgin-australia

On Virgin Australia's Velocity Frequent Flyer program (gold status), if I fly Singapore Airline and Swiss Airlines in a multi ticket business class, will I get points and status credits?

This frequent flyer program is not specifically in Star Alliance but I can easily join up with miles and bonus or KrisFlyer. There is also a Qantas flight in there but let's not confuse the problem.

Answer (score 1):

According to Virgin Australia for [Singapore Airlines](https://www.velocityfrequentflyer.com/content/Earn/Airlines/PointsEarn/#singaporeairlines):

**Earn Points with Singapore Airlines when you travel in an eligible fare class on flights with a SQ flight number that are operated by Singapore Airlines, SilkAir or Virgin Australia.**

However no credit for flights on Swiss Airlines.

See [wheretocredit.com](http://wheretocredit.com) to show where you can credit your [Swiss Airlines](http://www.wheretocredit.com/swiss) flights to:

> SWISS can earn miles on: Aegean Airlines, Air Canada, Air China, Air
>   India, Air New Zealand, All Nippon Airways, Asiana Airlines, Avianca,
>   Avianca Brazil, Cathay Pacific Airways, COPA Airlines, Egyptair,
>   Ethiopian Airlines, EVA Airways, Miles & More, SAS Scandinavian
>   Airlines, Singapore Airlines, South African Airways, TAP Portugal,
>   Thai Airways International, Turkish Airlines, United Airlines, United
>   Airlines

Comment: Thank you yes I believe so. I did apply for star alliance (Miles and More) membership. Can each leg of a flight be credited to different frequent flyer programs or do you just chose one and lose out on the flights that are not affiliated with that program. On this ticket there is 1 Singapore, 2 Swiss and 1 Qantas airline flights Thank you yall in business class.

Comment: @CQTiger It is possible to credit each leg to a different FFP, but it can be problematic in that your boarding pass might show which FFP you've configured for it but the old one gets credited due to synchronisation issues between various databases. You then have to fight to get credit in the programme you intended. Ask at check-in, gate or in lounge before each segment